# How to picture sinusioidal wave in transmission line(electrical circuit in general) ?

Tags: voltage, current, transmission-line

I have a friend who keeps asking how does a sine wave flow in transmission line. I've tried explaning him that it is the folw of charges in either directions but he isn't convinced yet . Can somebody give me a better explaination so that I can point him here to get the answer.

Comment: It is not flow of charges. It is a time varying electric field (and magnetic field). Assuming the transmission line is infinite, or terminated in its characteristic impedance, at any point on the transmission line, the electric field magnitude varies sinusoidally with time. You could probe it with an oscilloscope (in principle). As you move down the transmission line, you will see the same waveform but with time lag. So if you put a second probe there and put it on channel 2 of your oscilloscope, you will see that channel 2 is a delayed replica of channel 1. And so on down the line.

Comment: @mkeith you will hardly see the delay, because the scope needs a trigger and that will determine the position of the waveform

Comment: You have to have both channels on at the same time. You could trigger on channel 1. You would still see the delay between channel 1 and 2 (you could call it a phase lag). This was meant to be a conceptual exercise, although it is possible. If you had a very long delay line, and a high frequency signal, you could easily see the lag between channel 1 and channel 2. The delay line would need to have voltage taps of some sort. The whole thing would be much more complex if the line is not terminated in its characteristic impedance.

Comment: @mkeith yeah I understand :) sorry, that was just a pedantic observation but I think that the clarification was helpful too.

Comment: Get your friend to ask the question unless it's really you who needs the info and you might be too shy to say it is.

Comment: This type of test is easily performed by using a 500 or 1000 foot spool of cable. Drive one end of the cable where it enters the spool. Pull out the other end from the center of the spool and attach a proper termination. Then put the two scope probes to the two ends of the cable. Easy to see the delay. I did this once driving the cable with a monochrome monitor video signal. In the 497 feet of cable that I had it was possible to note a transmission delay down the cable that encompassed eight total pixel times of the video signal. Not a sine wave but still impressive at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear what your friend doesn't understand, but what you said is correct.

In a conductor like your transmission line, there are a number of free electrons, with enough energy to be outside the atoms' orbitals and in a state called "conduction band". these electrons are vibrating, or moving in a more or less random fashion. But if you look at them as a whole, they're on average still.

If you apply an electric field, they will be attracted by the point with the highest potential (they're negative charges) and away from the lowest. Therefore they will start drifting in that direction. Note that this movement is slower than the actual speed of the electrons, but still pretty fast: still in the order of magnitude of the speed of light.

An alternate voltage switches polarity following a more or less sinusoidal waveform. This means that the high potential changes from one side to the other. So the electrons will start drifting in one direction, than slow down until they're still again, and then reverse. Depending on the frequency of the sinusoid, they might actually never leave the cable, but if you're observing a section of it, you will see the oscillation.

If you add reactive components, the story gets a bit more complicated since they will affect the "sync" between the field intensity (voltage) and the flow (current).

Comment: With apologies and respect, I have to take strong exception to this way of looking at it. The free electrons are really a red herring. They just help to enforce the necessary boundary conditions to keep the energy inside the transmission line. The transmission line works by allowing an electromagnetic wave to travel through it. If you focus on electron flow in this case, you will be distracted from seeing the intuitive picture. In a typical transmission line (say coaxial cable), the EM wave moves through the dielectric between the conductors. The dielectric type determines propagation speed.